# how to add loop for many cells in excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

```
Sub table()

Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    ws.Cells(1, "C") = Format(ws.Cells(1, "A"), "yyyymmdd") & Format(ws.Cells(1, "B"), "hhmmss")
    ws.Cells(1, "C").NumberFormat = "0"
    Next ws

End Sub
```

this is my code for single cell(first cell). i want to run it for multiple cells by putting loop for i.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub table()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To 500 ' <-- Edit these numbers to modify the size of the iteration
            ws.Cells(i, "C") = Format(ws.Cells(i, "A"), "yyyymmdd") & Format(ws.Cells(i, "B"), "hhmmss")
            ws.Cells(i, "C").NumberFormat = "0"
        Next i
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: If your problem was solved, please indicate this to the rest of the readers by using the checkmark next to the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   for each cell in ws.range("C1:C1000")
      cell = Format(ws.Cells(1, "A"), "yyyymmdd") & Format(ws.Cells(1, "B"), "hhmmss")
      cell.NumberFormat = "0"
   next cell
Next ws
```

Comment: sorry sir code is not working.
showing error in //// cell.NumberFormat = "0" /////   line.
error is object required

one more thing u have written in line 3 ////ws.cells(1,"A"),"yyyymmdd"
1 is for 1 cell .i want to iterate it through all cells.